# Mongoose populate nested array with aggregate

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, mongoose-populate

I'm learning mongoose and I'm trying to populate everything from the account schema with the aggregate function.

I'm getting some trouble when I'm trying to populate the fields **$account.sessions.trades.closes.timeframe** and **$account.sessions.trades.tag**. The goal of the query is to get something like this

```
[
{ // trade 1
  name : "account-name",
  session : {name : "session-name"},
  trade : {
     symbol : {...},
     open : {....},
     closes : {
       gain : "12",
       timeframe : {time : 12, unit : "min"}
     },
     tags  : [
       {name: "tag-name-1"},
       {name: "tag-name-2"}
     ],

  }
},
{ // trade 2
 ...
},
{ // trade 3 
...
}
]
```

#### Account

```
const accountSchema = new Schema({
    name     : { type : String, required: true},
    sessions : [{
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : "Session_Model"
    }],
});
```

#### Session

```
const sessionSchema = new Schema({
    name         : {type : String}, 
    trades       : [{
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : "Trade_Model"
    }],
});
```

#### Trade

```
var operationSchema = new Schema({
    gain        : { type: Number },
    timeframe   : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Timeframe_Model"},
});

const tradeSchema = new Schema({
    symbol          : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Symbol_Model"},
    open            : operationSchema,
    closes          : [operationSchema],
    tags            : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Tag_Model"}],
});
```

#### Timeframe

```
const timeframeSchema = new Schema({
    time       : { type: Number, required: true },
    unit       : { type: String, required: true },
});
```

#### Aggregate query

```
Account_Model.aggregate(
                [
                    {$lookup : {
                        from         : "session_models",
                        localField   : "sessions",
                        foreignField : "_id",
                        as           : "populate_sessions"
                    }},
                    {$lookup : {
                        from         : "trade_models",
                        localField   : "populate_sessions.trades",
                        foreignField : "_id",
                        as           : "trade"
                    }},
                    
                    
                    {$unwind  : "$trade"},
                    {$sort    : {"trade.open.date" : 1}},

                    {$skip    : Number(req.params.limit) * (Number(req.params.page)-1)},   
                    {$limit   : Number(req.params.limit)},   

                    {$lookup : {
                        from         : "symbol_models",
                        localField   : "trade.symbol",
                        foreignField : "_id",
                        as           : "trade.symbol"
                    }},      
                    {$unwind : { path : "$trade.symbol"}},
                    {$lookup : {
                        from         : "timeframe_models",
                        localField   : "trade.open.timeframe",
                        foreignField : "_id",
                        as           : "trade.open.timeframe"
                    }},
                    {$unwind : { path : "$trade.open.timeframe"}},
                    {$lookup : {
                        from         : "session_models",
                        localField   : "trade.session_id",
                        foreignField : "_id",
                        as           : "session"
                    }},
                    {$unwind : { path : "$session"}},
                    {$match   : {}},
                    {$project : {
                        "name"          : 1,           
                        "trade"         : 1, 
                        "session.name"  : 1,                        
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ).then(accounts => { ... })
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add sample documents for each object or create a playground at the `https://mongoplayground.net` choosing the the bson multiple object template and add some sample documents and share the link in the question?

Comment: Hello,
This is the [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zrIbY7m6baz) to an example on Mongo Playground.